# Why can't I get the allocation source information?

Tags: ruby

#### 1. String

When I have a non-frozen non-interned string, I can get its source location (suppose the file name is `foo_file.rb`):

```
require "objspace"
ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start

obj = "foo"
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(obj) # => foo_file.rb
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourceline(obj) # => 4
```

When I have an interned string, the source location becomes unavailable (note the interning feature with `freeze` after a string literal):

```
obj = "foo".freeze
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(obj) # => nil
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourceline(obj) # => nil
```

I can confirm that this unavailability is not because it is frozen, but it is because it is interned:

```
obj = "foo"
obj = obj.freeze
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(obj) # => foo_file.rb
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourceline(obj) # => 4
```

Why can't I get the source information from an interned string?

#### 2. Regxp

When I have a regex, I can't get the source information even if it is not frozen:

```
obj = /foo/
obj.frozen? # => false
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(obj) # => nil
ObjectSpace.allocation_sourceline(obj) # => nil
```

Why can't I get the source location from a regex even when it is not frozen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two objects were simply allocated before the `ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start` call or any other Ruby code in this file was executed:

- `"foo".freeze` was allocated at [compile time by `rb_fstring()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/compile.c#L4797-L4811) (and originally also at [parse time](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/parse.y#L6507))
- the additional allocation of `"foo"` at run time happens only because internally `obj = "foo"` is actually similar to `obj = "foo".dup`. Take a look at the definition of the [`putstring` YARV instruction](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/insns.def#L343-L355) and the [`rb_str_resurrect()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/string.c#L1317-L1322) function for more details.
- `/foo/` was allocated at [parse time by `reg_compile()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/parse.y#L3972-L3988). That's it. No duplication here, so it's always the same object (no interning occurs though and it might be surprising behavior to some):

  ```
  3.times.map{ "foo".object_id }.uniq         # => [21063740, 21063720, 21063700]
  3.times.map{ "foo".freeze.object_id }.uniq  # => [21064340]
  3.times.map{ /foo/.object_id }.uniq         # => [21065100]
  ```